# What is the formula to calculate the scaled schoenfeld residuals for a coxPH model?

Tags: survival, residuals, cox-model, schoenfeld-residuals

I have managed to work out how to manually calculate the Schoenfeld residual for a coxPH model and i am getting the same answers as R.

However - i have absolutely no idea how to calculate the Scaled Schoenfeld residuals.

If anyone has the formula for these Scaled Schoenfeld residuals it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See `?residuals.coxph` for information on how to get these from R.

Answer (score 1):

On page 228 in [this book on Survival Analysis](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&lr=&id=bEZpGtw39qgC&oi=fnd&pg=PT11&dq=survival+analysis+liu+models+&ots=XApuoWZloi&sig=HqW2cyq-rmqQZ6h_hg5sYfU4qAM#v=onepage&q=survival%20analysis%20liu%20models&f=false) by Liu et. al. the formula for the scaled Schoenfeld residual for observation i and covariable m is described as:

$$
r_{im}^{\text{scaled schoen}} = \frac{r_{im}^{schoen}(\beta_m)}{V(\beta_m, t_i)}
$$

Where $V(\beta_m, t_i)$ describes the variance of the coefficient for the variable $X_m$. This is estimated via the observed Fisher-Information-Matrix that you presumably already calculated in the Fisher-Scoring-step for the estimation of the coefficients (negative 2nd derivative of Partial log-Likelihood w.r.t. all coefficients).

I think, intuitively this makes sense, as you scale the Schoenfeld residuals by the variance of the coefficient of interest. I am looking forward to your response on that - hope this short paragraph helps!

Comment: If I well understand, such standardization is the one proposed by Pettitt and Bin Daud (1990). As noted here:(https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2337123.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A1c715f39a9b0773ca34b470e7afef40e) it is only valid in case of if the covariates are uncorrelated at each time point. PETTITT, A. N. & BIN DAUD, I. (1990). Investigating time dependence in Cox's proportional hazards model. Appl. Statist. 39, 313-29.

Answer (score 0):

The scaled Schoenfeld residual for time $t_k$ is given by multiplication of the vector of Schoenfeld residuals at time $k$ by the inverse weighted covariance matrix of the (partial likelihood) estimate of the regression coefficients. See here:

([pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~dgillen/STAT255/Handouts/lecture10.pdf))

at pages 39-42.

Here:

([pdf](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2337123.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A1c715f39a9b0773ca34b470e7afef40e)) you can find the formula:

$r_{k}^*(\beta) = V^{-1}(\beta, t_k)r_k(\beta)$, where it is highlighted that everything depends on the $\beta$ vector of coefficients from the Cox regression,  $r_k$ is the Schoenfeld residual for events at time $t_k$, $r^*$ expresses scaled Schoenfeld residuals, $V^{-1}(t_k)$ is the covariance matrix of covariates for events at time $t_k$.